# Use ASSET API how to iterate a parent node in AEM?

Tags: java, adobe, aem

I have parent asset node inside the AEM CRXDE (/content/dam/parent). inside the parent node folder multiple child nodes are there .

Using Asset API how can i iterate the child nodes.?

After that i have to read/write properties.!

Code here:-

AssetManager assetManager=resolver.adaptTo(AssetManager.class);

Asset damAsset =assetManager.getAsset("/content/dam/parent");

Inside the parent node i have multiple child nodes.
ex:-

- /content/dam/parent/child1
- /content/dam/parent/child2
- /content/dam/parent/child3
  I need to access and read/write properties of these nodes.!

Comment: Show us what you have done - can't do much without showing us what you're actually going on about.

Comment: @OcelotcR i have updated the Question!

Comment: What's the type of the /content/dam/parent node?

Comment: /content/dam/parent  node is sling folder

Comment: why access sling folder as asset ? can you not do resolver.getResource('/content/dam/parent') and do getChildren on it ?

Comment: @SharathMadappa I was just checking using with Asset API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not get an Asset object from a non asset resource (a folder). The call to the getAsset method in your code will return a null, which is normal and as expected!

If you need to obtain the dam:Asset children, use the solution Sharath Madappa suggested in the comment to your question or even a SQL2 query like:

`final Iterator<Resource> allAssetChildren = resolver.findResources(
  String.format("SELECT * FROM [dam:Asset] AS node WHERE
    ISDESCENDANTNODE(node,'%s')", "/content/dam/parent"),
    javax.jcr.query.Query.JCR_SQL2
  );`

Finally, you can adapt any of the obtained resources to an Asset object using the adaptTo framework.

Answer (score 0):

Generally dam:Asset will not have children of type dam:Asset. An exception being sub assets. Sub assets are generated in situations where the main asset is composite. Few examples

- PDF, each page is extracted as a sub asset.
- PSD, each layer is extracted as a sub asset.
- Sub assets are extracted from AI story board.

In all such cases, the convention is to have these within a specific subfolder called **subassets**. When dealing with an `Asset` you can use `getSubAssets` method.

You cannot get a valid asset object by adapting folder node to Asset. To get assets in a folder use getChildren on the resource.

If you need to look within sub folders try node iteration/tree traversal for simpler use cases. You can use [Sling Query](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/sling-query.html) with the right search strategy.

JCR queries are not the most performant choice and you should only use if tree traversal is not an option for the use case.